# SVG chart move elements which do not fit on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, svg, charts

I use svg.js to draw my chart.  The chart is very specific, so I can't use some plugin to do it.

I have elements, rectangles, on my chart that are too long.  The problem is that I can't resize all elements to display the elements that are too long; I have to scroll.

How can I do this?

Solution 1:
Drag and move the SVG to change the position of all elements. 
This doesn't work when I use it on mobile device in browser; when I try to drag, the elements do not move, because browser goes into zoom mode.

My example: [image]

Element 2 is too long; it's svg rect.  Is it possible to allow scrolling horizontally?  Or, is there a way to move all of the element's on the chart?